# Create a Vagrant box template with changeable SSH key

Tags: ssh, vagrant, virtualbox

I'm actually creating a Vagrant box template to give to all the interns that come work here so that they don't need to lose one day to configure everything.

My question is: how can I clone the repositories by default and make the SSH key change on every new user ?

Thanks for your answers :)

Answer (score 0):

Your template should be basic and should not contain any user specific data. For your case Ansible/Chef/Puppet is appropriate way to provision your basic box.  That's how you can customize your box for specific concrete user.